# Scatter Gather with parallel flow (Timeout in aggregator)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've been trying to add a [timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator-xml) in the gather to don't wait that every flow finished.
but when I added the timeout doesn't work because the aggregator waits that each flow finished.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow queueFlow(LogicService service) {    
        return f -> f.scatterGather(scatterer -> scatterer
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(aFlow(service))
                                .recipientFlow(bFlow(service))
                        , aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.groupTimeout(2000L))
```

E.g of my flows one of them has 2 secs of delay and the other one 4 secs

```
public IntegrationFlow bFlow(LogicService service) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .handle(service::callFakeServiceTimeout2)
                .transform((MessageDomain.class), message -> {
                    message.setMessage(message.getMessage().toUpperCase());
                    return message;
                }).get();
    }
```

I use Executors.newCachedThreadPool() to run parallel.
*I'd like to release each message that was contained until the timeout is fulfilled*

Another approach that I've been testing was to use  a default gatherer and in scatterGather set the gatherTimeout but I don't know if I'm missing something
[Approach gatherTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637062/spring-integration-scatter-gather-pattern-with-jms-transport/45638790#45638790)

**UPDATE**

All the approaches given in the comments were tested and work normally, the only problem is that each action is evaluated over the message group creation. and the message group is created just until the first message arrived.  The ideal approach is having an option of valid at the moment when the scatterer distributes the request message.

My temporal solution was to use a release strategy ad hoc applying a GroupConditionProvider which reads a custom header that I created when I send the message through the gateway. The only concern of this is that the release strategy only will be executed when arriving at a new message or I set a group time out.

Answer (score 0):

The `groupTimeout` on the aggregator is not enough to release the group. If you don't get the whole group on that timeout, then it is going to be discarded. See `sendPartialResultOnExpiry` option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#agg-and-group-to

> If `send-partial-result-on-expiry` is `true`, existing messages in the (partial) `MessageGroup` are released as a normal aggregator reply message to the `output-channel`. Otherwise, it is discarded.

The `gatherTimeout` is good to have if you expect no replies from the gatherer at all. So, this way you won't block the scatter-gather thread forever: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather-error-handling

Comment: But when I put that option I don't receive any message from the gather.
I'd like to release all messages that are contained in the gather until the timeout is over

Comment: Are you sure that your service answers during those 2 seconds? Amy you need to wait a little more?

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/jandresboyaca/SpringIntegration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/deploysoft/cloud/flows/QueueIntegration.java

Comment: My goal is to release the messages that are in that moment and discard the others. So I have two flows one that takes 2 seconds and one that takes 4. My timeout could be 3 sec so I try to return  one message of the flow of 2 sec and discard the message of the flow that takes 4 sec

Comment: But I don't see `groupTimeout()` in your configuration. The `gatherTimeout()` does not help here: an aggregator still waits for all the messages to collect. And again: it is not perfect to test 2 seconds delay and wait for 2 seconds. The delay in reality might be a bit longer since resources busyness on your CPU.

Comment: Better to assume that service is going to answer within 1 second if you still want to wait for 2 seconds.

Comment: I don't chat. I have work to do and answer here whenever I have time. Sorry

Comment: Sry my bad. 
Now returns the first message and discard the other one and takes more time, I mean groupTimeout is the time to wait until the other message,
Does the aggregator always wait for all messages? Isn't there a way to free the group depending on a global timeout? Or would you have to create an ad hoc release strategy?

Comment: Oh! Yes; group timeout is re-started after each received message. Maybe you don't need to wait for the second reply at all and then simple `MessageCountReleaseStrategy` is enough for you?

Comment: And what do you think of `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`?

Comment: That's your choice. See its JavaDocs. Only the problem that `ReleaseStrategy` is not triggered until the message arrives to the aggregator. That was one of the reasons why we have introduced a `groupTimeout` feature.

Comment: That is a concern because I would have to wait N additional times for each message to validate the release strategy. Long story short there is no global time out that indicates that at the N time release the entire group.

Comment: There is. See `MessageGroupStoreReaper`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#reaper

Comment: In DSL , reaper will be all the configurations that I sent in messageStore method? by chance, do you have an example in DSL?

Comment: Not sure what the question. You declare `MessageGroupStoreReaper` `@Bean`. Inject into it the same `MessageGroupStore` you inject into the `gatherer`. And also see `@Scheduled` from Spring how to have a task in Java configuration : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

Comment: Artem Thanks for your help
This was my solution, Any suggestions?

https://github.com/jandresboyaca/SpringIntegration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/deploysoft/cloud/flows/QueueIntegration.java#L56

Comment: Looks good! But you don't need that `.taskScheduler(taskSchedulerTest)` for `gatherer`  since you don't deal with `groupTimeout` any more!

Comment: Arthem  I tested my approach but I don't know if I'm wrong
Because the repeat doesn't work as I expect . I explained my approach in the code
https://github.com/jandresboyaca/SpringIntegration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/deploysoft/cloud/flows/QueueIntegration.java#L56

Comment: I see. Try to `expireGroupsUponTimeout` to `false` on the `gather`. See its explanation in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator-xml - #23:   `When a group is completed due to a timeout (or by a MessageGroupStoreReaper), the group is expired (completely removed) by default.
Late arriving messages start a new group.`. That's probably what you are experiencing.

Comment: I think it is due to something in the message group, what I noticed was that the message group is created as soon as it receives the first message, so it is not taking into account the time of the first flow. I add expireGroupsUponTimeout but I have the same behavior

Comment: I think I will have to use an ad hoc release strategy which will send a header with the time of when I start the flow and valid with a timeout global. obviously, this release strategy will execute until the first message arrived

Comment: Yes, it consults the creation time of the group which is, essentially, a reply from the fastest sub-flows.

Comment: Is there a way to kwow when a message was trigger into a flow?

Comment: See `ChannelInterceptor` abstraction: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-interceptors. Your `queueFlow` has an input channel as `queueFlow.input`. So, you can declare a `ChannelInterceptor` bean with a `@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "queueFlow.input")`. However it might be better to start the flow from the `PublishSubscribeChannel` and have another flow subscribed to it to react to the same message differently.

Comment: See this JIRA for another option how to handle your use-case: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2208